# JSP inner function printing

Tags: java, jsp, printing

Should be direct HTML printing in a JSP declaration tag function legal?

```
<%! void recursivePaintLevels(List<String> things, int deepLevel){ %>
    <ul class="level-<%=deepLevel%>">   
         <% for (int i=0; i<things.size(); i++){ %>
             <li class="whatever">
                             //(...)
            </li>
         <% } %>
    </ul>
<% } %>
```

And then call it like this in normal JSP body flow:

```
 //(...)
 <% recursivePaintLevels(things, 1); %>
```

I mean would be like using same normal JSP logic of implicit out.println() but in a method.
For me it is not working (Eclipse says 'Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete TryStatement') but I am not sure if my error has something to do with it.

I also know I should use JSLT and EL, but this is my choice.

Comment: First of all, avoid java code where ever possible.

Comment: And then, avoid scriptlets, at least. And then, when you have an error, tell us what it is. But it looks like you're mixing `<%! %>` with `<% %>`, which I wouldn't think would work. You're free to make whatever choices you want, of course, but this is a poor decision, on multiple levels.

Comment: The readers of this site clearly favor top ranked users but hardly care to evaluate the answers given. The question is not about the best practices but whether it is possible to declare some method in jsp and use it later which is pretty much possible. Google it :)

Comment: Thank you! But some precision note. The question asks for the <% syntax inside a JSP method declaration as a way of avoiding doing out.print for every peace of HTML code. I already know for sure methods can be declared :)

Comment: i have seen only out.println() with in the body of the method for ui content, but you could make a quick test with simple content (say just one <div> helloworld </div> and then test yourself by calling this method. I wish i had some webapp setup to test this :(

Comment: It is not working but maybe I am missing something, I cannot believe the only option is print manually every line :'(

Comment: Looks like out.println is the only way for this problem because adding scriptlet in the body of the method makes this method discontinuos in the generated java file (where other member variables and methods become part of this method). Apologies for providing the wrong solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe this is pretty much legal and  valid though a bad practice.I think the problem here is because of the double quotes `"level-<%=deepLevel%>"`
Try separating that using

```
<% String str= "level-"+deepLevel; %>
```

and then use
    `<ul class="<%=str%>">` .

or simply replace the whole line with out.println

**EDIT**:

It appears that the body of the methods in jsp should not have any scriptlets. I have tried to embed one scriptlet with no content and observed that the generated java file adds the first part  (from delcaration to the content before scriptlet )at the begging and the remaining part of the method at the end (and all member variables and other method declarations become part of this method). Apologies for providing wrong answer (as i have noticed that behavior with the cached jsp).

Looks like out.prinltn is the only solution for this problem

Comment: Downvoter care to explain why this is not legal. There are numerous articles that declare methods in JSp and use them later with in that jsp

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not legal. The JSP page is effectively implemented as one big method that executes all of the code within the page. In java, you can't simply insert other methods nested within a method.

You code would generate something like this:

```
public void _jspService(...) {
    ...
    void recursivePaintLevels(...) {
        ...    
    }
}
```

And that's simply not legal java.

Instead you should defer the code to a utility library class bundled with your web app.

You MIGHT be able to create a recursive tag file, I have not tried that.

Comment: I believe this is pretty much legal. this might not be placed inside _jspservice at all.

Comment: It is legal if you declared as declaration <%! but this is not my question

Comment: This is actually not legal in a sense that adding scriptlets with in the body of the method declaration makes that generated method discontinuous and other members/methods become part of this method (_jspService() becomes part of recursivePaintLevels() but not the other way)